# creating new table based on slicer selection in power bi using DAX

Tags: filter, dax, slicers

I am new in Power Bi, so if anyone help in the following scenario then it will be very helpful for me.

suppose i have two tablse as

Table 1 =

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

and Table 2 =

| Sl. No | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Now, I will put Table 1 in the slices visualization and it will have multiple selections. Using the slices selection, I want to create a new table that filters Table 2 using DAX.
For e.g. suppose I select the rows with names "B" and "C". I am expecting the return table as follows:

| Sl. No | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

I have tried the following DAX but did not get the required result

```
selected list = 
var selected_list = ALLSELECTED(Table 1[Name])
return
    CALCULATETABLE(
        'Table 2'
        ,FILTER(
            'Table 2'
             ,CONTAINSROW(selected_list, 'Table 2'[name])
         )
    )
```

Comment: If you are trying create a physical table based on slicers selection - it's not possible.

Comment: @Mik , instead of "selected_list", if i make it as "CONTAINSROW({"B", "C"}, 'Table 2'[name])" then it is giving the required result. is there any way to put "selected_list" in "{"_", "_"}" format?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a physical table based on slicer selection. It's not possible.

All physical tables should be evaluated by DAX before they are uploaded to a data model or refreshed.

You can create only a virtual table with slicers values, but you cant `RETURN` it as a result of the measure. You can use this virtual table for intermediate calculations, but a measure that uses slicers values should return `Scalar` value, not a table.
To get all values from the slicer like this:

```
VALUES('Table 2'[name])
```

but it should be a correct syntax in the measure.

If you want to make a visual named `Table` or `Matrix` then can do following steps:

1. Link tables in your data mode `Table 1` and `Table 2`. `Table 1` should filter `Table 2` like this `Table 1` -> `Table 2` (link `Table 1[Name]` and `Table 2[Name]` columns).
2. Then create a slicer of `Table 1[Name]`.
3. Choose your value/values.